# Monte Carlo Gradient Estimator

Tags: monte-carlo, unbiased-estimator, estimators, gradient

How do we derive this Monte Carlo Estimator?
\begin{equation}
\nabla_{\phi}\mathbb{E}_{q_{\phi}(z)}[f(z)] =
\mathbb{E}_{q_{\phi}(z)}[f(z) \nabla_{q_{\phi}(z)}\ln q_{\phi}(z)] 
\end{equation}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming we can interchange the derivative and integral operator,

$$\nabla_\phi \int f(z) q_\theta(z) dz = \int f(z)  \nabla_\phi q_\theta(z), $$

and then note that by the chain rule,

$$\nabla_\phi \ln q_\theta(z) = \frac{\nabla q_\phi(z) }{q_\phi(z)} \Rightarrow \nabla q_\phi(z) = \nabla_\phi \ln q_\theta(z) q_\phi(z), $$
and the result just follows.

Comment: Thank you very much. And what if $f$ depends on $\phi$ ?

Comment: You use the product rule, $(f\cdot g)' = f'\cdot g + f \cdot g'$ and thus you retain the term above plus an additional term with the gradient of $f$ included. I would recommend math.stackexchange.com if you need help with derivatives.